# Use Field Value as where clause statement

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer

is it possible to use the select statement result as where clause statement/Condition in oracle SQL? Eg:

```
Condition_txt(FIELD) = 'AND 
b.mpal03d >= TO_DATE('01/10/2012','DD/MM/YYYY')' 
(Value of field)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you'll need dynamic SQL.

Here's an example.

This is result we expect:

```
SQL> select count(*)
  2  from emp
  3  where hiredate >= to_date('01/12/1981', 'dd/mm/yyyy');

  COUNT(*)
----------
         5
```

Table that contains conditions; I set it to *one condition per table* as I don't know how it actually looks like in your case:

```
SQL> select * From filter;

TAB CONDITION
--- ----------------------------------------------------
EMP  and hiredate >= to_date('01/12/1981', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Code:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_str         varchar2(500);
  3    l_table_name  filter.table_name%type := 'EMP';
  4    l_condition   filter.condition%type;
  5    l_cnt         number;
  6  begin
  7    select f.condition
  8      into l_condition
  9      from filter f
 10      where f.table_name = l_table_name;
 11
 12    l_str := 'select count(*) from ' || l_table_name ||
 13             ' where 1 = 1 ' || l_condition;
 14
 15    execute immediate l_str into l_cnt;
 16
 17    dbms_output.put_line('Number of rows = ' || l_cnt);
 18  end;
 19  /
Number of rows = 5

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```